# What's the point of glMultiDrawElements?

Tags: opengl

I was calling `glBindVertexArray` and `glDrawElements` many times to draw VAO / VBO pairs and found that regardless of the size of the VBO / Indices for each mesh, calling `glDrawElements` too many times causes a large bottleneck, so I started looking into `glMultiDrawElements`.

I thought, cool, I'll just call that function instead of using a for loop! No, it seems I have to create a new merged VBO and Indices. Once more, from the few examples I was able to find online, it seems the indices reference the entire VBO. I was expecting multiple offsets of indices, each starting at 0 with the respective offset of the start of each mesh in the VBO. Now I have to add offsets to each index after the first mesh.

At this point, I might as well just make one big VAO / VBO / Indices for all the meshes and call `glDrawElements` a single time. If the meshes were identical then I would just use `glDrawElementsInstanced`.

So, my conclusion is that `glMultiDrawElements` is pointless, not to mention the atrocious *indices* parameter which could really be improved. What am I missing, what is the point of this function?

Comment: The purpose of [`glMultiDrawElements`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMultiDrawElements.xhtml) is to draw multiple meshes, which are specified in one VAO and one index buffer, with one draw call. The fact that it does not meet your needs does not mean that it is useless. The vertices and indices of multiple meshes can be concatenated in one vertex buffer and one index buffer.

Comment: glMultiDrawElements allows you to do things that aren't easily possible by just issuing a single glDrawElements on the VAO/VBO. Especially, you get `gl_DrawID` in the shaders which allow you to pick material data or transformations per object from a UBO or SSBO.

Comment: Will just make one big VAO / VBO / Index then and use ```glDrawElements```. I still see no point. Someone enlighten me with the -1.  I've looked into ```gl_DrawID``` a bit, will admit I'm not too familiar with it but it sounds similar to instancing. Will look into it some more.

Comment: @ddxm: "*At this point, I might as well just make one big VAO / VBO / Indices for all the meshes and call glDrawElements a single time.*" But that would draw them, in order, from front to last. You wouldn't be able to choose determine the order of them.

Comment: @ddxm: "*Someone enlighten me with the -1.*" I didn't give your question a downvote, but broadly speaking, the tone of your question is needlessly hostile. It might have gone better if the question were framed more as "I tried to put all of my meshes into the same buffers to gain multidraw performance, but I had problems X, Y and Z. Are there solutions to these?" rather than "This function doesn't seem to work, but everyone says to use it."

Comment: +/- should be associated with question validity, not politeness. But you're right, most people prefer sugar on it. I'll make questions and responses to others happy going forward!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A drawing command can be [given a base vertex index](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Base_Index), per the function `glDrawElementsBaseVertex`. The "base vertex" is an index that is added to every index read from the index buffer *before* using it to fetch the vertices from the vertex buffer. This should allow you to not have to manually increment the indices yourself when shoving all of your meshes into the same buffer.

There is a multidraw equivalent to this: `glMultiDrawElementsBaseVertex`, where each draw call in the multidraw operation is given its own base vertex.

And of course the [indirect rendering version of multidraw](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Indirect_rendering) comes with base vertices as part of the multidraw data.

Comment: Nice, I'd be curious to see the performance difference between offsetting all indices and setting base vertices. I assume the latter would be a fair bit faster since it knows certain vertices will not be used with each mesh.

Comment: @ddxm: Well, since one of them requires CPU work modifying each index and the other requires... absolutely nothing (that field exists whether you're using it or not), I'm not sure why we would need to measure anything.

Comment: After the Buffers have already been created, would calling ```glDrawElements``` or ```glMultiDrawElementsBaseVertex``` be faster? The former requires the entire range of indices and vertices to be available for each mesh. I don't know if OpenGL is smart enough to take advantage of that or not.

Comment: @ddxm: They *both* require "*the entire range of indices and vertices to be available for each mesh*". See, once you take all of the index creation stuff off the table, the only functional difference is how many function calls you make. That question isn't really worth investigating; pick the smaller number.